# How to serialize recursive relationship with self in Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, recursion, django-rest-framework, serialization

consider the below assumptive models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sub_category = models.ManyToManyField(u'self', null=True, blank=True,
                                          through=u'SubCategory', symmetrical=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    from_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name=u'from_category')
    to_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name=u'to_category')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.from_category.name
```

How could We have a serializer to serialize a recursion relationship like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "a",
    "sub_category": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "b",
            "sub_category": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "c",
                    "sub_category": [
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "name": "d",
                            "sub_category": [
                                ...
                            ],
                        },
                        ...
                    ],
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try the `djangorestframework-recursive` package, available here: https://github.com/heywbj/django-rest-framework-recursive

Comment: When I used this module, I got a RuntimeError with Exception Value: `maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__`

Comment: Right - so you probably have a cycle in one of the relationships. You need to figure out how you want the representation to deal with that.

Comment: thank you. you should embed this recursive field in DRF

Comment: It's better left as a third party package - helps us to spread the maintainance & documentation tasks across a wider range of people, rather than having to provide for a huge number of possible use-cases directly in the core package.